# Can I use setQuery from within a Google Apps Script Gadget?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets, google-sites, google-gadget

I'm creating a line graph using the Google Visualization APIs that pulls in data from a Google spreadsheet.  When I run it locally, it works perfectly.  But when I embed it in a Google apps script gadget on my Google site, I noticed that the setQuery function is ignored.  Upon doing some research, it looks like this might be by design and you can't run queries from within the script gadget.  Is that the case?  If so, do you know another way of pulling in a specific range of data instead of an entire sheet?

This is the query I'm using in my script:

```
query.setQuery("SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H WHERE A >= datetime '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND A < datetime '2013-09-01 00:00:00'");
```

Comment: Are you using the Apps Script implementation of the Visualization API, or the standard javascript implementation?

Comment: That's a good question.  I didn't realize there was an Apps Script implementation.  I think I'm just using the standard JS implementation.  My apps script just loads an html page that has all of the visualization stuff in it.  Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You Have a gadget " awesome Table". He load a Spreadsheet with a query. You add interactive control.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G9JiOOFT5VKYGITvrLdlv0pBnJM0rXdrruSd91zAcCM/edit